# What is an adjective that connotes "implied" and "hidden"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

"Analytical skills are used to uncover _________ data."

In the context of Data Science or Computer Science, I am trying to find a word that conveys "hidden" / "implied" / "underlying". As to say that once data manipulation and cleaning is done, some pattern can be deduced.

Comment: Note: all adjectives are words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found:

**Latent** - *(of a quality or state)* existing but not yet developed or manifest; hidden or concealed

Comment: This is often used in a technical sense to refer to extracting latent fingerprints, which seems like a useful allusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word **underlying**—which you seem to have already glossed over. In particular, if discovered only after investigation, the following [sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlying):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> 2 : evident only on close inspection : IMPLICIT

---

Although *implicit* is a synonymous adjective, it's not as well-suited to the context as *underlying* itself.